# How to access nested value that starts with @?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to access @total value in this case?

It's comes from callback of Rubykassa gem:

```
config.success_callback = ->(notification) { PaymentsController.new.on_payment_success(notification) }
```

to my controller method:

```
def on_payment_success(notification)
    a = notification[:@invoice_id]
    @payment = Payment.find_by_invoice_id(invoice_id.to_i)
    @account = @payment.account
    @payment.update_attribute(:status, 'paid')
    Transaction.up_balance(@total, @account)
    if @payment.user.price_plan.price == 0
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path, notice: ''
    else
      redirect_to groups_path, notice: ''
    end

  end
```

**UPDATE**

The question is about syntax. In case of regular hash

```
notification: {invoice_id: '101', total: '500}
```

I can access value of `invoice_id` by  `notification[:invoice_id]`  but `notification[:@invoice_id]` not works. How to get value?

[image]

Comment: Can you give any context?

Comment: @RichardPeck added. I've tried different ways. Just can't understand how to access it from code.

Comment: If you can access the `@invoice_id` then it should be possible to access `@total` the same way.

Comment: I can't do it also)) total is given just for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the screenshot, `@total` is an instance variable of the `Rubykassa` object. You can't access it using the hash-like syntax, as it's not a Hash.

My assumption is confirmed [by the source code](https://github.com/ZeroOneStudio/rubykassa/blob/b2e632e6fcbf2cb1e24893318a7a47f23263cf5f/lib/rubykassa/notification.rb)

```
module Rubykassa
  class Notification
    include SignatureGenerator

    attr_accessor :params

    def initialize(params)
      @params = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(params)
      @invoice_id = @params["InvId"]
      @total = @params["OutSum"]
    end

    %w(result success).map do |kind|
      define_method "valid_#{kind}_signature?" do
        @params["SignatureValue"].to_s.downcase == generate_signature_for(kind.to_sym)
      end
    end

    def success
      "OK#{@invoice_id}"
    end
  end
end
```

`@total` doesn't seem to be publicly exposed by the class, hence *it may not be meant to be accessed directly*.

Ruby is a quite permissive language, hence you can still access it by either using `instance_variable_get` or definiting a custom accessor:

```
notification.instance_variable_get(:'@total')
```

or

```
module Rubykassa
  class Notification
    attr_reader :total
  end
end

notification.total
```